# Rcpp slower than R for a sampling p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

### Problem setting

The problem consists of sampling out of a year of 365 days `n` days, in such a way that

- the days are drawn by uniform probability distribution
- the days comply to have a minimum distance given by `min_dist`
- the result is given as numeric vector

### Example

With `n= 12` and `min_dist= 20` a proper result might be the vector
`[1]   4  43  69  97 129 161 192 215 243 285 309 343` as `diff` of this vector is `[1] 39 26 28 32 32 31 23 28 42 24 34`, all values larger or equal to `min_dist= 20`.

### Question

I have solved this problem with

- function `sample_r()` in native `R`
- function `sample_cpp()` in `c++` using the fantastic `Rcpp` interface package

The `c++` solution turns out to much slower (on my Mac factor 60x). I am a `Rccp` newbie, hence my own research capabilities are limited - please forgive.
***What can I do to refactor the `c++` code to be faster than native `R` code ?***

### Reproducible code (`.cpp file`)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector sample_cpp(int n, int min_dist= 5L, int seed= 42L) {
  
  IntegerVector res_empty= Rcpp::rep(NA_INTEGER, n);
  IntegerVector res;
  IntegerVector available_days_full= Rcpp::seq(1, 365);
  IntegerVector available_days;
  IntegerVector forbidden_days;
  IntegerVector forbidden_space = Rcpp::seq(-(min_dist-1), (min_dist-1));
  bool fail;
  Environment base("package:base");
  Function set_seed = base["set.seed"];
  set_seed(seed);
  do {
    res= res_empty;
    available_days = available_days_full;
    fail= FALSE;
    for(int i= 0; i < n; ++i) {
      res[i]= sample(available_days, 1, FALSE)[0];
      forbidden_days= res[i]+forbidden_space;
      available_days= setdiff(available_days, forbidden_days);
      if(available_days.size() <= 1){
        fail= TRUE;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  while(fail== TRUE);
  std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
  return res;
}


/*** R
# c++ function
(r= sample_cpp(n= 12, min_dist= 20, seed=1))
diff(r)


# R function
sample_r= function(n= 12, min_dist=5, seed= 42){
  if(n*min_dist>= 365) stop("Infeasible.")
  set.seed(seed)
  repeat{
    res= numeric(n)
    fail= FALSE
    available_days= seq(365)
    for(i in seq(n)){
      if(length(available_days) <= 1){
        fail= TRUE
        break()
      }
      res[i]= sample(available_days, 1)
      forbidden_days= res[i]+(-(min_dist-1):(min_dist-1))
      available_days= setdiff(available_days, forbidden_days)
    }
    if(fail== FALSE) return(sort(res))
  }
}

(r= sample_r(n= 12, min_dist= 20, seed= 40))
diff(r)

# Benchmark
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(cpp= sample_cpp(n= 12, min_dist = 28),
          r= sample_r(n= 12, min_dist = 28),
          replications = 50)[,1:4]

*/
```

Benchmark:

```
    test replications elapsed relative
1  cpp           50  28.005   63.217
2    r           50   0.443    1.000
```

---

#### Edit:

OK, I tried to optimize (as far as I am capable of `c++`), still the `c++` implementation is behind, but now only marginally.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector sample_cpp(int n, int min_dist= 5L, int seed= 42L) {
  
  IntegerVector res;
  IntegerVector available_days;
  IntegerVector forbidden_days;
  IntegerVector forbidden_space = Rcpp::seq(-(min_dist-1), (min_dist-1));
  bool fail;
  Environment base("package:base");
  Function set_seed = base["set.seed"];
  set_seed(seed);
  do {
    res= Rcpp::rep(NA_INTEGER, n);
    available_days = Rcpp::seq(1, 365);
    fail= FALSE;
    for(int i= 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if(available_days.size() < n-i){
          fail= TRUE;
        break;
      }
      int temp= sample(available_days, 1, FALSE)[0];
      res[i]= temp;
      forbidden_days= unique(pmax(0, temp + forbidden_space));
      available_days= setdiff(available_days, forbidden_days);
    }
  }
  while(fail== TRUE);
  std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
  return res;
}


/*** R

# R function
sample_r= function(n= 12, min_dist=5, seed= 42){
  if(n*min_dist>= 365) stop("Infeasible.")
  set.seed(seed)
  repeat{
    res= numeric(n)
    fail= FALSE
    available_days= seq(365)
    for(i in seq(n)){
      if(length(available_days) <= n-i){
        fail= TRUE
        break()
      }
      res[i]= sample(available_days, 1)
      forbidden_days= res[i]+(-(min_dist-1):(min_dist-1))
      available_days= setdiff(available_days, forbidden_days)
    }
    if(fail== FALSE) return(sort(res))
  }
}

# Benchmark
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(cpp= sample_cpp(n= 12, min_dist = 28),
          r= sample_r(n= 12, min_dist = 28),
          replications = 50)[,1:4]

*/
```

Benchmark:

```
  test replications elapsed relative
1  cpp           50   0.643    1.475
2    r           50   0.436    1.000
```

Comment: There are some obvious bits that are probably less than fast.  `forbidden_days= res[i]+forbidden_space;` being one. But any answer will be a stab in the dark.  You should really get a profiller to measure which part is taking all the CPU time and then look into how you can fix that.

Comment: Do both functions return the same result?

Comment: Nobody said that it was impossible to write poorly performing C++ code. That is why we benchmark.  Rethink your approach, work at it and _likely_ you may end up beating R code with C++ code.

Comment: @Roland: They don't.  I got `"Mean relative difference: 0.06066634"` from `all.equal` but I don't have time to fix this for the OP.

Comment: @Roland: both implementations return correct results according to task. To my understanding as both RNGs form `R` and `Rccp sugar` are not synced, identity is not a test.

Comment: @user2030503 You just wrong. Try `set.seed(42); rnorm(3);` followed by `cppFunction("NumericVector rn(int n) { return Rcpp::rnorm(3, 0, 1); }")` and `set.seed(42); rn(3)`.  The numbers will be same.  That is in almost all Rcpp intros, and maybe you should do some re-reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your R version by sampling the largest possible number of days in one shot.

The following code is faster than yours. Statistically I sample the majority of the days before the loop. The remaining days are sampled in the loop but the loop is likely to run only once. Maybe twice.

Moreover it is easy to rewrite with Rcpp.

```
sample_r2= function(n = 12, min_dist = 5, seed = 42)
{
  available_days = seq(365)

  res = sort(sample(available_days, n))
  y = diff(res)
  res = res[y >= min_dist]

  while (length(res) < n)
  {
    forbidden_days = sapply(res, function(x){ x + -(min_dist-1):(min_dist-1) } )
    available_days = setdiff(available_days, forbidden_days)

    days = sample(available_days, n - length(res))
    res = sort(c(res, days))

    y = diff(res)
    res = res[y >= min_dist]
  }

  return(res)
}
```

Btw maybe there are some issues in my code. But I think the idea is correct.

Comment: thx for your R implementation proposal. `sample_r2(n= 12, min_dist = 30)` yields an error, while `sample_r(n= 12, min_dist = 30)` works a requested. Moreover the question was more heading towards refactoring the c++ code to be faster than native R code. Thx again.

Comment: I know that your question was about C++. But writing a more efficient algorithm in R will help you to write an efficient C++ code as well.